# If/Guard Clauses in React/Redux Components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a React component that is being rendered and some initial data isn't available just yet. Because of that, I have these two `if` blocks (guard clauses) that check to see if we're in a state to even bother rendering. Basically, when this component is used, we're in a state where we have header records for the data, but none of the detail records yet. So this component is recognizing that and retrieving the detail before displaying.

This *feels* wrong, like this isn't the way it should be done in React/Redux. Further, that second `if` block could possibly cause an infinite loop. It basically checks to see if we have detail data for a header record. If not, we return and call `props.onSortItemChanged()` to begin the process of fetching the data. What if the data doesn't exist? Then we'd come back here and make the call again. Anyway, that's just one issue.

The main issue is that I believe a component like this shouldn't know or care about having to fix/retrieve data. It should just display with data that's already in a correct form. Is that right? If so, where is the right place to check and make sure the data is in good form? The action? The reducer?

```
  render() {
    const {
      printSortOptions,
      printSortDetails,
      selectedPrintSortOption,
      printSortDrawerEvent
    } = this.props;

    if (printSortDrawerEvent === printSortDrawerEventTypes.CLOSE ||
        printSortDrawerEvent === printSortDrawerEventTypes.FAIL) {
      return <div id="emptyDiv" />;
    }

    if (printSortOptions && printSortDetails.length === 0) {
      const selectedOptions = printSortOptions.filter(o => o.isDefault);
      this.props.onSortItemChanged(selectedOptions[0]);
      return this.constructor.loadingJsx();
    }

    const selectedPrintSortDetails = printSortDetails.filter(
      d => d.printSortOption.printSortId === selectedPrintSortOption.printSortId)[0];

    return (
      <div className="col-xs-12">
      // remaining JSX here
    )
  }
```

Comment: how could it create infinite loop? I think you are doing eveything correctly. The only thing you can do is to separate your component into 2 components. One handling the layout - the dumb component, one handling the conditions (the smart component). Or, if all your reducers have the same format, you can wrap the loading check to a high level component.

Comment: After calling `this.props.onSortItemChanged()`, the state will change and we'll render again. If that `if` condition is still true, we'd make the call again. Then we'd make the call again, render again, etc.

Comment: True. You shouldn't have that there at all. That should be part of a reducer.

Comment: Ok, so that's what I'm getting at. Is it the reducer's responsibility to detect missing data and change the state? If so, how would it initiate/dispatch another call?

Comment: There are various ways. You can use actors (trigger an action when a specific part of state changes) or you can simply chain the actions (if you are using redux-thunk then action is a promise and you can simply use `.then` to trigger another action. There are many solutions but you should definitely keep them away from rendering.